MySQL remove duplicate distinct values
Wondering if it's possible to remove results with the same value.
I have a payments table containing ADJUSTMENTS and REFUNDS entered as AJUSTE and ESTORNO. While both can exist in an invoice, if the total sum of each are equal, they are to be ignored. If the sum of each are not equal, then will be considered for calculation.
I have come up with a list of each as follows:
select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, pay_date, active, invoice_no, invoice_date 
from payments 
where pay_type = 'AJUSTE' 
    and pay_date like '%-%-2024' 
    and active = '1' 
    and pay_amount not in (
        select SUM(pay_amount) as pay_amount 
        from payments 
        where pay_type = 'ESTORNO' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
        group by invoice_no
    ) 
GROUP BY invoice_no;


Then this query for the opposite:
select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, pay_date, active, invoice_no, invoice_date 
from payments 
where pay_type = 'ESTORNO' 
    and pay_date like '%-%-2024' 
    and active = '1' 
    and pay_amount not in (
        select SUM(pay_amount) as pay_amount 
        from payments 
        where pay_type = 'AJUSTE' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
        group by invoice_no
    ) 
GROUP BY invoice_no;


Although refunds are negative, I want to exclude all amounts that are the same and add the ones that are different.
Is this possible through a query in MySQL 5.7?
---- edit ------
I have created a fiddle with demo data: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6qxcOxSlkuv
AJUSTE (Adjustements) are positive number in the DB meanwhile ESTORNO (refunds) are negative amounts.
When a refund is applied, an adjustment must follow in the same amount to zero out the balance on an invoice. There are scenarios where an adjustment can exist without a refund when the client doesn't pay the full balance, correct an error, etc. In this case, we need to know the pay_amount and pay_type of this adjustment.
It is also possible that there may be 2 adjustments and only 1 refund. Ex. Client paid half the balance and a refund of that half payment was applied, plus a full adjustment to write-off the invoice.
The query must look at each individual invoice. When the sum of all refunds and adjustments within the same invoice exists and adds up to zero, we skip over that particular invoice.  If the sum of adjustment is more than refund or vice versa, we want the pay_type (AJUSTE or ESTORNO) with the difference (pay_type). (ex. ESTORNO 100, AJUSTE 500. Must output AJUSTE 400).
The query you provided in the answer returns invoices 78 and 79.
Invoice 79 has ESTORNO 100 and AJUSTE 551.20 which is correct.
Invoice 78 has ESTORNO 100 and AJUSTE 200 which is also correct.
Invoice 55 has AJUSTE 2000 and doesn't show up on the results.
Hope this all makes sense.
--- second edit -----
If the sum() of AJUSTE and ESTORNO in an invoice_no is the same, it gets ignored - do not include in results.
If the sum() of either AJUSTE or ESTORNO in an invoice_no is different, show both results as a positive number.
Payment_id is the primary key. My apologies as the mysql fiddle didn't include it.
Expected result from mysql fiddle:


Note that in the WHERE clause, pay_amount refers to the values in the table, not SUM(pay_amount) AS pay_amount. To filter the aggregated value you have to put the condition in HAVING.

thanks for the info Barmar. Can you show me an example of how that would look like?

See another example
Condition When the sum of all refunds and adjustments within the same invoice exists and adds up to zero, we skip over that particular invoice.
So first step - Calculation sum for pay_type in ('AJUSTE','ESTORNO') for every invoice_no.
We take invoices, where total sum is not <>0.
Subquery.
select invoice_no
  ,sum(pay_amount) sum_AE
from payments p
where pay_type in('AJUSTE','ESTORNO') and pay_date like '%-%-2024' 
     and active = '1'
group by invoice_no
having abs(sum(pay_amount))>0.001




invoice_no
sum_AE




55
2000


78
100


79
451.20000000000005



Full query.
Inner join previous output with payments table
select p.invoice_no,abs(pay_amount) pay_amount,pay_type
from payments p
inner join(
   select invoice_no 
     ,sum(pay_amount) sum_AE
   from payments p
   where pay_type in('AJUSTE','ESTORNO') and pay_date like '%-%-2024' 
       and active = '1'
   group by invoice_no
   having abs(sum(pay_amount))>0.001
 )c on p.invoice_no=c.invoice_no
where pay_type in('AJUSTE','ESTORNO')
order by p.invoice_no ;




invoice_no
pay_amount
pay_type




55
2000
AJUSTE


78
200
AJUSTE


78
100
ESTORNO


79
551.2
AJUSTE


79
100
ESTORNO



fiddle

Wow... you did it. Thank you!

Join your subqueries and show only the rows that have different sums for the same invoice.
SELECT e.*
FROM (
    select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, invoice_no
    from payments 
    where pay_type = 'ESTORNO' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
    group by invoice_no, pay_type
) AS e
JOIN (
    select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, invoice_no
    from payments 
    where pay_type = 'AJUSTE' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
    group by invoice_no, pay_type
) AS a ON a.invoice_no = e.invoice_no AND a.pay_amount != e.pay_amount

UNION ALL

SELECT a.*
FROM (
    select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, invoice_no
    from payments 
    where pay_type = 'ESTORNO' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
    group by invoice_no, pay_type
) AS e
JOIN (
    select sum(pay_amount) as pay_amount, pay_type, invoice_no
    from payments 
    where pay_type = 'AJUSTE' and pay_date like '%-%-2024' and active = '1' 
    group by invoice_no, pay_type
) AS a ON a.invoice_no = e.invoice_no AND a.pay_amount != e.pay_amount

DEMO
To avoid ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY errors you have to remove the pay_date, active, and invoice_date columns from the SELECT list, since they may not be unique within the groups.

I appreciate the example Barmar, but I'm using MySQL 5.7. Can it be done in 5.7?

Replace FROM e JOIN a with FROM (subquery) AS e JOIN (subquery) AS a, substituting the definitions of each CTE for subquery.

I appreciate your time and effort, but the query didn't provide what I am looking for.  Basically, it needs to sum all AJUTES and all ESTORNO from each invoice. If the sum amounts of AJUSTE are the same as the sum amount of ESTORNO per invoice, it should be ignored and not returned as a result.

I think that's what this does. It does separate sums for AJUTES and ESTORNO in each subquery, then compares the sums.

Can you add sample input data and expected results to the question? Enter it as text so it can be copied and pasted for testing.

HI Barmar. Thanks for pursuing this issue. I edited the question since the text was too long to place in here. Thanks in advance!

Do you need to cancel individual payments and adjustments with the same amounts, or just the totals? Please edit the question to add expected results. Also, you need to make payment_id the primary key of the table at mycompiler.io, otherwise it gets an error from GROUP BY payment_id.

Hi Bamar, I edited the question again. My fiddle didn't mark payment_id as the primary key. In the database it is the primary_key. sorry about that.

Please don't post images, post text.

Actually, there's still a grouping problem. We're grouping by invoice_no, not the primary key. You can't have other non-aggregated columns in the SELECT list, since they could have different values in different rows in the group.

Good to know. I can't change the structure of the db at this point so I'll need to come up with an alternative for the report.  I appreciate all your effort once again. Thank you

Change it to just SELECT invoice_no, pay_type, SUM(pay_amount) AS pay_amount FROM ... GROUP BY invoice_no, pay_type. Get rid of all the columns, since they won't be unique.

But ideally you should normalize your tables. There should be another table of invoices, and invoice_no should be the FK.

I needed to change YEAR(pay_date) back to your original LIKE condition. I didn't realize it was a VARCHAR, I assumed it was a DATE.

I've made a fiddle showing the results.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
